# C++,Copy all csv files in a dir to a new file

Tags: c++, file

I Have n csv files in a directory. I need to copy all these files in new file. But header should copy only once.
One way to solve this issue was to use batch file

```
copy /b *.csv Combine.csv
```

but it copies  n headers of these  n files.

The other solution

I put all these files in a vector and iterate through it.

```
std::vector<std::string> file_vec;
```

But I am not sure if it is good solution and how can I make it efficient. Any suggestion please?

I am using window 10, VS 2019, C++17.

The files are

20210731_000000_datastore3.csv

20210801_000000_datastore3.csv

20210802_000000_datastore3.csv

20210803_000000_datastore3.csv

---

---

---

Comment: If you want to combine N csv files into 1 csv file, you are doing to need to open up each one and copy it's data into the csv file that will have the combined data.

Comment: **Hint**: Read in files line by line and append them to the target file skipping the first line of the input file if the target is not empty. By the way, the purpose of the site is not to write code for other peoples. What have you tried? Obviously, if you don't need the data, there is no point in filling a vector as you can process the whole thing file by file and line by line and be able to handle files that are quite large.

Comment: Does each *.csv file start with a header row? If so, in your batch file command example, I think your Combine.csv file would have multiple header rows within the csv, which may cause troubles later, depending on how the data is parsed/used.

Comment: this sounds like a job for a bash script rather than c++.

Comment: If I am reading this question correctly, you have solved this problem and you want to know if your solution is "good" and "efficient".  Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends a little bit on your operating system.

But usually `dst << src.rdbuf();` is not that bad.

Complete solution would then be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

std::vector<std::string> sourceFileName{

    "20210731_000000_datastore3.csv",
    "20210801_000000_datastore3.csv",
    "20210802_000000_datastore3.csv",
    "20210803_000000_datastore3.csv"};

const std::string destinationFileName{ "combine.csv" };

int main() {

    if (std::ofstream destinationFileStream{ destinationFileName }; destinationFileStream) {
        bool ignoreHeader{};
        for (std::string& filename : sourceFileName) {

            if (std::ifstream sourceFileStream{ filename }; sourceFileStream) {

                if (std::string throwAway{}; std::exchange(ignoreHeader,true)) std::getline(sourceFileStream, throwAway);
                destinationFileStream << sourceFileStream.rdbuf();
            }
            else std::cerr << "\nError: Could not open source file '" << filename << "'\n";
        }
    }
    else std::cerr << "\nError: Could not open destination file '" << destinationFileName << "'\n";

    return 0;
}
```

But there are tons of other solutions . . .

Comment: Your advanced use of C++17 `if` statement with initializer makes this an overly complicated answer in my opinion. Looks like you're actively trying to minimise the number of lines of code.

Comment: Hm, opinions are different. I think, you refer to the line with the "throwAway" variable, because, opening files in the above way is rather "standard". In general I am a fan of narrow scopes. I even think that this is more safe. And the variable "throwAway" is just used in this one statement. Nowhere else. Then, why should I introduce it in other scopes? Additionally: I think, "if with initializer" was exactly introduced for this purpose. But as said. It is a matter of opinion or style, and everybody will do as he likes. So, no issue . . .